# how to pass position index to scrollTo

Tags: jquery, navigation, scrollto

I have implemented localscroll/scrollto in one of my projects.
Since yesterday there was only 1 navigation which were scrolling through whole site.

But now i need to add two separate arrows (previous/next) to scroll to next or previous section of page content.

What I have at the jquery level is:

```
$('#menu').localScroll(800); //this is for upper menu (simple ul/li/a)


// this whole code below is for those two arrows: prev/next 
function scrollToPosition(element) {
    if (element !== undefined) {
        $("body").scrollTo(element, 800, {
            margin: true
        });
    }
}


$(function() {

    //Create an Array of section
    var section = $('#container .section');
    position = 0; //Start Position, its 0 by default and here is my problem
    var next = $('.next');
    var prev = $('.prev').hide();

    next.click(function(evt) {
        //Scroll to next position
        prev.show();
        scrollToPosition(section[position += 1]);
        if (position === section.length - 1) {
            next.hide();
        }
    });

    prev.click(function(evt) {
        //Scroll to prev position    
        next.show();
        scrollToPosition(section[position -= 1]);
        if (position === 0) {
            prev.hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Where you can see position = 0; - thats my problem, I would like to pass an index of clicked menu link.

In upper menu I have like 10 links.
When I click 5th I would like to prev/next arrows know that and actualize position to 5, so that when Im scrolled to 5th content container and will click prev/next it wont start from 0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your markup as well? It will really help solve your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable, and bind an onClick function to your 10 links that updates the value of that global variable. Then have position = 0 look at the global variable at runtime to set the position;

```
 var position = 0;

 function setPosition( linkID ){
        if (linkID !== undefined) {
             if (linkID < 11) { //Or whatever other varchecking
                 position = linkID;
             }
         }
  }

  $(function() {

  //Create an Array of section
  var section = $('#container .section');
  //Position is already set here
  } 
  </script>


  <a href='#link1' onClick='setPosition(1);'>Do Stuff!</a>
```

You can overcomplicate it/do other stuff but that's the quick and dirty

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly then you want to get the index of the menu item clicked so you can scroll to that element which is stored in a jQuery object. You will then pass this element to the `.scrollTo()` function which will get the position of the element for you. If this is the case then:

```
$('ul').children().bind('click', function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    scrollToPosition(section[index]);
});
```

This will target your menu `<ul>` element, find its children (assuming the `<li>` elements are direct children of the `<ul>` element), then binds a `click` event handler to the `<li>` elements to get the index of the clicked element (it's easier to do this with the `<li>` elements instead of the `<a>` elements because the `<li>` elements are all on the same tier of the DOM; they are all siblings).

Here is the documentation for `.index()`: http://api.jquery.com/index

Also you should put a `var` statement in-front of your `position` variable declaration so it's not a global variable (it will still be accessible from the `document.ready` event handler, the only part of your code that accesses this info):

$(function() {

```
//Create an Array of section
var section  = $('#container .section'),
    position = 0, //Start Position, its 0 by default and here is my problem
    next     = $('.next'),
    prev     = $('.prev').hide();
```

Notice the variable declarations are separated by commas which will add them all in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
//Store the index when clicked on any menu
$('#menu li').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().data("menuindex", $(this).index());
});

//Here you can use that index to determine the position
next.click(function(evt) {
    position = ($('#menu').data('menuindex') || 0)
    //Scroll to next position
    prev.show();
    scrollToPosition(section[position += 1]);
    if (position === section.length - 1) {
        next.hide();
    }
});

prev.click(function(evt) {
    position = ($('#menu').data('menuindex') || 0)
    //Scroll to prev position    
    next.show();
    scrollToPosition(section[position -= 1]);
    if (position === 0) {
        prev.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: You could use `$.data` which is quite a bit faster than `.data()`: `$(this).parent().data("menuindex", $(this).index());` would change to: `$.data($(this).parent()[0], "menuindex", $(this).index());` and `$('#menu').data('menuindex')` would change to: `$.data($('#menu')[0], 'menuindex')`

Comment: @Jasper - I think accessing just 1 attribute will not make much difference. But if you have plenty of data attributes then your suggestion makes sense thanks anyways.

Comment: It works... almost, when clicking the prev/next they only scroll +1 or -1 container, never further. Could you please checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9002420/1167656

Answer (score 0):

Use classes to keep track of the active element. Then use its offset position to scroll it into view. This obviates the need for global variables and other hacks. This code could be consolidated a bit, but the premise is sound.

http://jsfiddle.net/aVvQF/25/

```
$('#prev').click(function() {
    var $targetElement = $('.active').prev('.section');

    if (!$targetElement.length) {return;}
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $targetElement.addClass('active');

    //scroll element into view    
    $('html, body').clearQueue().animate({scrollTop: $targetElement.offset().top }, 1000);
});

$('#next').click(function() {
    var $targetElement = $('.active').next('.section');

    if (!$targetElement.length) {return;}
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $targetElement.addClass('active');

    //scroll element into view    
    $('html, body').clearQueue().animate({scrollTop: $targetElement.offset().top }, 1000);
});
```